# Azure front door, how to set route action according to the origin？

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

just like, if it goes to a.com, the request will take header info like key=a automatically,
if it goes to b.com, the request will take header info with key=b automatically.

I find the rule sets condition [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rules-match-conditions?pivots=front-door-standard-premium&tabs=portal),but which condition should i choose?[image]

Comment: while clicking on  [privacy](https://i.imgur.com/rdqmh4L.png) to the home to able to [route](https://i.imgur.com/gC3T9Zr.png)

Comment: @Sampath hi,the rule sets of front door didnt have a condition called backend pool.

Comment: I will sample examples of how to Route

Comment: sorry about commits about the rules

Comment: Other [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76210588/azure-front-door-classic-redirect-to-new-domain-and-prepending-to-the-url/76215331#76215331)

Answer (score 1):

### Route action in Front Door and CDN

Reference :

> I Referred this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/routing-methods) for Front Door  , @[Rohit Sharma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCN4JbZ9Svk) and for [deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?pivots=development-environment-vs&tabs=net70) of web app.

I Created a sample web app  with [home , privacy](https://i.imgur.com/yTHZnjL.png) and connected the web app service with Front Door.

[image]

- The respective Front door which created can be access at [Endpoint](https://i.imgur.com/yTHZnjL.png)
- Create the origin group and the origin

[image]

- After updating the [origin](https://i.imgur.com/XSdktux.png) add the  configure the [Routes](https://i.imgur.com/clRkwjB.png) to new origin.
- In  Front Door Manager click add [route](https://i.imgur.com/0C6fNBg.png)

[image]

- After creating [route](https://i.imgur.com/Pl9Drbb.png) While click on [privacy](https://i.imgur.com/ZvCQrfq.png) it will Route to default page.

**Output**  :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but maybe front door not support for my idea. I have made a case for azure tech support and i'm waiting for a response.