# Azure Front Door Classic redirect to new domain and prepending to the URL

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I need to redirect from front door classic to another domain but on a specific path and keep the rest of the URL.

so I`m going from Google.com/search/v4/root to bing.com/base/search/v4/root the options offered in front door for the redirect are not so great. On the receiving side I have a front door Premium if that helps.

The redirect of the Front door classic.

[image]

but as opposed to url rewrite I don`t have the option to preserve unmatched path so when I setup as above I just get a static redirect.

Thank you in advance, best community ever.

Adding multiple redirect points.

Comment: will give a sample example of how to redirect. not sure about redirecting from google to bing.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from Azure Front Door Classic to a new domain while preserving the rest of the URL, I  use the URL Rewrite feature.

> I followed this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect?pivots=front-door-standard-premium) for front door and @[sampath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76205511/azure-front-door-how-to-set-route-action-according-to-the-origin/76208522#76208522).

[image]

**Steps :**

- In the navigation pane on the left side of the screen, select the "Routing Rules". The "+ Add" button can be used to add a new routing rule.
- Set "Match Variable" to "Request path" and "Operator" to "Matches the Pattern" in the "Match Condition" section. Enter the precise path you want to match for the redirect in the "Value" column.
- Set the "Action Type" to "URL Rewrite" in the "Action" section.
- Enter the new domain and the path you want to attach in the "Rewrite URL" field.
- Set the "HTTP Status Code" to "Permanent Redirect (301)" in the "HTTP Response" section.
- To save the new rule, press the "Add" button.ensure that the most specific rules are assessed first, make sure you order the rules properly. This can be accomplished by clicking the "Priority" column heading in the "Routing Rules" blade to arrange the rules according to priority. By testing the URLs that should be redirected, you can make sure the redirects are functioning properly.

[image]

- I deployed a sample application to app service, linked the Front Door with app service from the top stack reference, updated the rules and was able to route.

**Output** :

[image]

Comment: Hei, thank you, but I need a forward with rewrite

Comment: for rewrite   Rule set configuration refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite?pivots=front-door-standard-premium)